# how to make 2 or more picker views in swift

Tags: swift, uipickerview

so i want to make 2 picker views but my problem is everytime i call the text field they only call one pickerview i already tried replace and make 2 function with different value but the function didnt work when i run it
here is my code i think the problem is because pickerview function but i dunno how to replace the code to add condition if user click jenisIDTextField the pickerview will show array of jenisID and if the user choose provinisTextField the pickerview will show array of provinsi

i appreciate all answers 
thanks for all your help !

```
@IBOutlet weak var provinsiIdentitasTextField:
@IBOutlet weak var jenisIDTextField:
```

func choosePicker(){

```
    let pickerView = UIPickerView()

    pickerView.delegate = self


jenisIDTextField.inputView=pickerView
provinsiIdentitasTextField.inputView = pickerView

}

 let provinsi=["DKI Jakarta","Jawa Barat","Sumatra Utara"]
    let JenisID=["KTP","SIM","Passport"]
var asd = 0

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {



        return provinsi[row]

}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
  return provinsi.count

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {


        return provinsiIdentitasTextField.text=provinsi[row]


}
```

Comment: You have created only one pickerView and in both textfield you have assigned same pickerView as input view.So, you are getting same value. So, now you want to make two picker view?

Comment: Check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238224/multiple-uipickerview-in-the-same-uiview

Answer (score 1):

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{

    if pickerView == pickerView1 {
        //pickerViewdetails
    } else if pickerView == pickerView2{
       //pickerView2details
    }}
```

You can publicly declare pickerviews and use above code to add multiple pickerviews.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it, hope it's working for you.

```
    //declare variable
        let yourArray : [String] = []

    //implement textfiled delegate
            func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
                if textField == provinisTextField{
                    yourArray = ["DKI Jakarta","Jawa Barat","Sumatra Utara"]
                }else if textField == jenisIDTextField{
                    yourArray = ["KTP","SIM","Passport"]
                }
            }


//implement picker Delegate
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return provinsi[row]
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
      return provinsi.count

    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            return provinsiIdentitasTextField.text=provinsi[row]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Complete Code of implementation:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textFieldOne: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldTwo: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

var isForWhichTextField:Int = 0

var arrForDisplay:[String] = [String]()

let provinsi = ["DKI Jakarta","Jawa Barat","Sumatra Utara"]
let JenisID = ["KTP","SIM","Passport"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textFieldOne.inputView = pickerView
    textFieldTwo.inputView = pickerView
    arrForDisplay = provinsi
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
   return arrForDisplay.count
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return arrForDisplay[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    return textFieldOne.text = arrForDisplay[row]
}

//MARK:- UITextfields Delegates

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == textFieldOne{
        arrForDisplay = provinsi
        pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    }else{
        arrForDisplay = JenisID
        pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    }
    return true
}}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A small Correction for @Jaydip's answer.

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            return provinsiIdentitasTextField.text=provinsi[row]
    }
```

this always assign value to the provinsiIdentitasTextField textfield only, whichever textfield you select.So create a new text field and assign the selected textfield to that

```
      var selectedField: UItextField?

     //implement textfiled delegate
                func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

                    if textField == provinisTextField{
                        yourArray = ["DKI Jakarta","Jawa Barat","Sumatra Utara"]
                    }else if textField == jenisIDTextField{
                        yourArray = ["KTP","SIM","Passport"]
                    }
              selectedField = textField

            pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
                }
```

///assign the selected text field

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
                return selectedField!.text= yourArray[row]
        }
```